# Iterate through a dictionary in data-frame and evaluate using condition

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

My dataframe is of the format:

```
 id                            text                                    occurrences  

001 Ad sales boost Time Warner profit\n\nQuarterly...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia':
003 Yukos unit buyer faces loan claim\n\nThe owner...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 
004 High fuel prices hit BA's profits\n\nBritish A...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 
005 Pernod takeover talk lifts Domecq\n\nShares in...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 
... ... ... ...
506 Trial begins of Spain's top banker\n\nThe tria...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 
507 UK economy ends year with spurt\n\nThe UK econ...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 
508 HealthSouth ex-boss goes on trial\n\nThe forme...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 
509 Euro firms miss out on optimism\n\nMore than 9...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 
510 Lacroix label bought by US firm\n\nLuxury good...   {'argentina': 0, 'australia':
```

I'm trying to convert the `dtype` of the `occurrences` (count of all occurences of countries) column into a dictionary so that I can do something like this:

```
for x in df['occurrences']:
    if x.values() >=1:
        df['iscountrymentioned']='True'
    else: df['iscountrymentioned']='False'
```

but when I do this:

```
df['occurrences'].astype(dict)
```

I'm getting the error :

```
TypeError: dtype '<class 'dict'>' not understood
```

I know I'm doing something horribly wrong here as running this part of the code without type conversion is giving me all False values in `iscountrymentioned`:

```
for x in df['occurrences']:
    if x.values() >=1:
        df['iscountrymentioned']='True'
    else: df['iscountrymentioned']='False'
```

Without type conversion is giving me

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Yes, it does...because I also want a count of how many times that specific key, ie country name is mentioned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One way to solve the problem:* You can use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to apply a custom function `func` on the values of `occurrences` series. In `func` you can use the [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to deserialize the value in `occurrence` series to python `dict`.

```
import json

def func(s):
    try:
        d = json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
        return True if len(d) > 0 else False
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        return None

df["iscountrymentioned"] = df["occurrences"].apply(func)
```

*Sample Result:*

```
>>> print(df)
  id                                               text                       occurrences  iscountrymentioned
0   1  Ad sales boost Time Warner profit\n\nQuarterly...  {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 1}                True
1   3  Yukos unit buyer faces loan claim\n\nThe owner...  {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 2}                True
2   4  High fuel prices hit BA's profits\n\nBritish A...  {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 3}                True
3   5  Pernod takeover talk lifts Domecq\n\nShares in...  {'argentina': 0, 'australia': 4}                True
```

Comment: Im quite the noob, Could you please tell me what you did here?   Also, do you have any insights as to why im not being able convert the dtype of column `occurrences`

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami We've used `apply` function on the series `occurrences` which call the  function `func` for each value present in `occurrences`. Then we've deserialized that value using `json.loads` method to create a dictionary `d`. Then you can check if `d` contains any keys if so then you return `True` otherwise `False`

Comment: idk why I'm getting `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` if i use your solution

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami Are you sure `occurrence` column contains data items like `{'argentina': 0, 'australia': 1}` or maybe it also contains something else?

Comment: I'm sure, it is a  dictionary with key=country names and value= occurrences of those country names in the `text` field. feel free to look it up, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgZMUlHFngw4i6rui9sXT4VzNfXJdxbag0vPxLkkYGo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: also idk how im getting another error as well now.`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'`